# Daily Coding Problem 316 : Coin Change Problem - determination of denomination?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I'm going through the Daily Coding Problems and am currently stuck in one of the problems. It goes by:

> You are given an array of length N, where each element i represents
> the number of ways we can produce i units of change. For example, [1,
> 0, 1, 1, 2] would indicate that there is only one way to make 0, 2, or
> 3 units, and two ways of making 4 units.
>
> Given such an array, determine the denominations that must be in use.
> In the case above, for example, there must be coins with values 2, 3,
> and 4.

I'm unable to figure out how to determine the denomination from the total number of ways array. Can you work it out?

Somebody already worked out this problem [here](https://github.com/vineetjohn/daily-coding-problem/blob/master/solutions/problem_316.py), but it's devoid of any explanation.

From what I could gather is that he collects all the elements whose value(number of ways == 1) and appends it to his answer, but I think it doesn't consider the fact that the same number can be formed from a combination of lower denominations for which still the number of ways would come out to be 1 irrespective of the denomination's presence.

For example, in the case of `arr = [1, 1, a, b, c, 1]`. We know that denomination 1 exists since `arr[1] = 1`. Now we can also see that `arr[5] = 1`, this should not necessarily mean that denomination 5 is available since 5 can be formed using coins of denomination 1, i.e. (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Are there are a limited number of coins available, or a limited number of denominations that you can use arbitrarily many of each coin of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're solving the coin change problem, the best technique is to maintain an array of ways of making change with a partial set of the available denominations, and add in a new denomination `d` by updating the array like this:

```
for i = d upto N
    a[i] += a[i-d]
```

Your actual problem is the reverse of this: finding denominations based on the total number of ways. Note that if you know one `d`, you can remove it from the ways array by reversing the above procedure:

```
for i = N downto d
    a[i] -= a[i-d]
```

You can find the lowest denomination available by looking for the first 1 in the array (other than the value at index 0, which is always 1). Then, once you've found the lowest denomination, you can remove its effect on the ways array, and repeat until the array is zeroed (except for the first value).

Here's a full solution in Python:

```
def rways(A):
    dens = []
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        if not A[i]: continue
        dens.append(i)
        for j in range(len(A)-1, i-1, -1):
            A[j] -= A[j-i]
    return dens

print(rways([1, 0, 1, 1, 2]))
```

You might want to add error-checking: if you find a non-zero value that's not 1 when searching for the next denomination, then the original array isn't valid.

For reference and comparison, here's some code for computing the ways of making change from a set of denominations:

```
def ways(dens, N):
    A = [1] + [0] * N
    for d in dens:
        for i in range(d, N+1):
            A[i] += A[i-d]
    return A

print(ways([2, 3, 4], 4))
```